# How to generate XML with correct character encoding?

Tags: java, xml

I have this code:

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
doc.appendChild(rootElement);

Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
rootElement.appendChild(staff);

Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
attr.setValue("1");
staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("† José do Capêta †"));
staff.appendChild(firstname);

TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(writer));
String output = writer.getBuffer().toString();

System.out.println(output);
```

That must generate a XML file.
This XML should have the characters as i wrote in the code, with the special characters and everything.
But when i run, the outpus is this:

```
<company>
<Staff id="1">
<firstname>† José do Capêta †</firstname>
</Staff>
</company>
```

So, when i try to open it with any xml reader, it gives me an error because it can not read those special characters.

I know it should generate the following XML, i just don't know how to do it:

```
<company>
<Staff id="1">
<firstname>&#8224; Jos&#233; do Cap&#234;ta &#8224;</firstname>
</Staff>
</company>
```

So what is the solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't generate your xml to a *String* or *Writer*.  Generate the xml to *bytes* and write the bytes directly to a file (or generate directly to a file).  By generating the xml to a String/Writer, you are generating the xml using the platform default character encoding.  In general, you should use "utf-8" unless you have a really good reason not to (which is generally what the xml library will do on it's own if you write to a OutputStream instead of a Writer).

Comment: But if i need only the String?

Comment: @MateusViccari - how are you openeing it with an xml reader if you only need the String?

Comment: I am saving the output by copying the text from the console to a new file.

Comment: @MateusViccari-  if your ultimate destination is a file, you should be writing to a FileOutputStream.

Comment: Then we need to know what console it is and what encoding it has and what the editor has - Much more controllable to write from Java to a file

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, i was creating the file with windows as then pasting the content and saving. In this way windows creates the file with it's own encoding (ISO-885-1 i believe). I tried to create the file with notepad++ and saving with UTF-8 encoding and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You should use ByteArrayOutputStream to write out the XML and then convert it to a String.

```
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), result);
String output = bos.toString("UTF-8");
```

**[Edit]**

If you need to write the bytes to file, you can do the following:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("someName.xml")) {
  fos.write(bos.toByteArray());
} catch (IOException ioe) {
  ioe.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my memory serves me right, the problem is the method you're calling. Try using `setTextContent`

For example

```
firstname.setTextContent("† José do Capêta †");
```

That should escape the text automatically.

Comment: no, creating a text node will get escaped correctly as well.

Answer (score -1):

You could use escapeXML from the `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` library, So you could use:

```
String foo = StringEscapeUtils.escapeXML("& # shall be escaped!");
```

You can also use an external library.

Comment: no, this is not what you want to do.  you should use the xml libraries correctly, not hack the output after the fact.